# Terminal emulator in android just hangs when I type su?

Tags: rooting, root-access, terminal, troubleshooting

I'm fairly new to Linux so sorry for my noobiness. Anyways I just wanted to check that my phone was rooted since I need an app that requires it to be rooted, but nothing happens in the app. I wanted to double check that it was rooted so I typed su in the terminal emulator but nothing happens. I still type but the next terminal line doesn't appear even after 10 minutes. No error or permission denied, it just skips to the next line and does nothing. If it helps, I rooted using Kingo.

Comment: The emulator needs permission to grant the root access. Are you getting a message prompt from Kingo when you typed in su?

Comment: No I am not. I uninstalled some of the apps that came with it like the superbattery and kingo link so I'm not sure if that had anything to do with it

Comment: Thats the problem. You needed those apps because third-party rooting apps have been know to give you "temporary" root access. The best solution is to root the phone again with kingo, install a custom recovery, and then flash SuperSu.     SuperSu is better and gives you a better experience with better binaries.

Comment: I installed TWRP, and I granted root access but the window only says "Requesting root access" with a loading symbol. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try rooting with KingRoot

Comment: I used a root checker app and it says that root access is not properly installed on my device even though Kingo said that it installed correctly. I'm trusting the rootchecker app more though, should I try restoring to factory settings then trying again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KingROOT will root your phone successfully. Remove KINGO and install KingRoot apk. [image: Kingroot]

Comment: Using the Kingo apk worked perfectly. Thank you.